# Invalid use of void expression in strcmp

Tags: c++, strcmp

I am looking to check if two string are permutations of each other. I am using the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

void sort(char *str)
{
    char temp;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if(str[i]>str[i+1])
        {
            temp=str[i];
            str[i]=str[i+1];
            str[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char string1[10],string2[10];
    int val;
    cout<<"Enter first string";
    gets(string1);
    cout<<"Enter second string";
    gets(string2);
    val = strcmp(sort(string1),sort(string2));
    if(val==0)
    {
        cout<<"Same strings"<<endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout<<"Different Strings"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting a "invalid use of void expression error" at the strcmp line. How do I fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: Your sort function is `void`: `void sort(char *str)`. You can't use it with `strcmp()`.

Comment: **NEVER** ever use `gets`. It's been removed from both C and C++ because of its complete disregard for security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to compare strings after sorting. Assuming your `sort` function does the right thing, you need to compare the strings *after* sorting them.

```
sort(string1);
sort(string2);
val = strcmp(string1, string2);
```

The reason for the error is that your `sort` function returns `void`. So you are effectively passing `void` arguments to `strcmp`. And that can't work.

The way to do this in C++ would be to use `std::string`, and call `std::sort`.

```
std::string string1, string2;
std::cout << "Enter first string";
std::cin >> string1;
std::cout << "Enter second string";
std::cin >> string2;
std::sort(string1.begin(), string1.end());
std::sort(string2.begin(), string2.end());
bool val = string1 == string2;
```

Comment: Except there's already an algorithm for this (in C++11 at least): `std::is_permutation` :) It's even better in C++14 since you don't need to worry about different lengths.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that function :). I am looking to implement it manually though. But I seem to get "different string" displayed each time. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

`sort` returns nothing (`void`), so its return value cannot serve as parameter to `strcmp`.

```
sort(string1);
sort(string2);
val = strcmp(string1, string2);
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. However, there is apparently a logical problem here as I am still getting a "different strings" even if i put same strings as input. Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't `strcmp` the `void` returns from `sort()`.  You want to `sort()` first and then `strcmp` the sorted strings, something like:

```
sort(string1);
sort(string2);
val = strcmp(string1, string2);
```